# displaying data from more collections in one form in mongodb, node.js,express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

we are doing an e-commerce project using node.js,express,and mongodb

in that while adding entries in the from the dropdown data should be displayed from the collection

Now, my query is that how can i extract the data from two or more collections

```
/*routing(in user.js)*/
 var addInvoice=require('../crud/addInvoice.js');
 router.get('/invoice',function(req,res) {
 product.find()
   .then(function(doc) {
    res.render('invoice',{items:doc});
    });
});
router.post('/addInvoice',addInvoice.addaInvoice);    

 /* now for dislaying
 /* invoice.handlebars

 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label"          for="productName">productname</label>
     <div class="col-md-4">
       <select id="productName" name="productName" class="form-control">

      {{# each items }}

      <option value="{{ this.productid}}"> {{ this.productname}}</option>
         {{/each}}
 </select>'
```

from the above code i can display the data from the product collection

now take vendor as another collection

now i have to display the data from product and vendor in a same form how can     i combine two collections.....

i have tried some basic functions like concatination and so on but it does not worked .. can u please help me....

```
    /*product schema 




  var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    //var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
    var autoIncrement = require('mongoose-auto-increment');
    //var autoref = require('mongoose-autorefs');
    // Product Schema
    var productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        productid: Number,
      productname: String,
        productcode: String,
      productcategory: String,
        productsubcategory: String,
        productbrand: String,
        colour:String,
        size:String,
        vendorName:String,
    //  productvendor:  String,
      productimage:  String,
      articlename: String,
      articlenumber:Number

    },{collection: 'product-data'});


    productSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, {model: 'product', field: 'productid' });
    productSchema.methods.dudify = function() {
      // add some stuff to the users name
      this.productcode = this.productcategory.substring(0,2)+this.productbrand.substring(0,2)+'000'+this.productid;

      return this.productcode;
    };
    var product = module.exports = mongoose.model('product',productSchema);
    //productSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin,{model:'product',field: 'productid'});


        var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var autoIncrement = require('mongoose-auto-increment');
    //var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

    // Product Schema
    var vendorSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        vendorid: Number,
      vendorname:String,
      category:String,
      subcategory:String,
      brand:String,
        emailid: String,
        phoneno:Number,
        TXNnumber:Number,
        city:String,
      address:String

    },{collection: 'vendor-data'});

    var vendor = module.exports = mongoose.model('vendor', vendorSchema);
    vendorSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, { model: 'vendor', field: 'vendorid' });
```

Comment: I think by "from" means "form" right ?

Comment: Can you show the DB schema for the two collections? Is a way that they both are connected or referenced?

Comment: Do you want to get `product` and `vendor` data in same call `/invoice`?

Comment: yes , In my invoice product name ,vendor name are dropdown ,the drop down to be populated from their collections that is vendor name drop down should be taken from vendor collection and as well as product from product collection

Comment: /* vendor schema

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var autoIncrement = require('mongoose-auto-increment');
//var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');


var vendorSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 vendorid: Number,
  vendorname:String,
  category:String,
  subcategory:String,
  brand:String,
 emailid: String,
 phoneno:Number,
 TXNnumber:Number,
 city:String,
  address:String

},{collection: 'vendor-data'});

var vendor = module.exports = mongoose.model('vendor', vendorSchema);
vendorSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, { model: 'vendor', field: 'vendorid' });

Comment: i have added schemas